# How to import JSONArray to ArrayList<>?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer;
import net.simonvt.menudrawer.Position;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import adapter.MyRecyclerAdapter;
import app.AppController;
import data.FeedItem;


public class CategoryMain extends Activity {

    private static final String URL_FEED = "http://lorempixel.com/800/400/nightlife/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final CatRecyclerAdapter adapter;
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter = new CatRecyclerAdapter(createMockList(), R.layout.item));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<ViewModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, ViewModel viewModel) {
                adapter.remove(viewModel);
            }

        });

    }




//
    private  List<ViewModel> createMockList() {
        List<ViewModel> items = new ArrayList<ViewModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            items.add(new ViewModel(i, "Item " + (i + 1), URL_FEED + (i % 10 + 1), i + ""));
        }
        return items;

    }


}
```

I don't know how to import JSON Data to Arraylist. How can I import JSON Array in createMockList() ? Someone help me! I'm beginner. Sorry for my poor english. Thanks You!
I want to know how to replace with JSON Array?

Comment: Check this link: http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2013/04/convert-json-array-to-string-array-list-java-from.html

Comment: You can't just "import" json data, but you can parse it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java